# Volunteer or Voluntary Organisation

Tags: word-choice

I belong to an organisation which consists of volunteers. We do voluntary work. Would one describe this as a **volunteer organisation** or a **voluntary organisation**?

I have seen both expressions used widely, but am uncomfortable with the latter.

Comment: Usage-wise they mean the same. In fact, a *volunteers'* organization is more often called a "voluntary organization" than a "volunteer organization." The latter sounds like a hastily put together group of sundry volunteers.

Comment: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/voluntary-organization.html ; http://thelawdictionary.org/voluntary-organization/ ; http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Voluntary_organization&redirect=no

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree that one is used "more often" than the other; examples of both usages abound. The [Red Cross](http://www.redcross.org/va/richmond/volunteer) identifies itself as "the largest volunteer organization in the United States." Websites like [this one](http://sterlingpr.com/resourceposts/list-of-volunteer-organizations/) list "Volunteer Organizations"; there are also Volunteer Organization [fairs](http://www.leadershipandservice.ufl.edu/programs/volunteer_organization_fair/), [books](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=0809258374), etc.

Comment: @J.R - nice links, which just highlight how widespread both forms are in use. There does not even appear to be a geographically or culturally defined boundary in my investigations.

Comment: @Kris - I'm happy to accept that 'usage-wise they mean the same'; my preference for use still lies with 'volunteer organisation', for reasons none other than I would say 'Wilderness Society', 'Scout Association' or 'Canoe Club'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**volunteer organization** refers to an organization comprised of volunteers.

**voluntary organization** refers to an organization which is, itself, voluntary (optional?)

The former would be the most correct in your example.

Comment: Can you cite the source?

Comment: @Kris - No source, just my own experience. I have never heard the term "voluntary organization," though I have heard "volunteer organization" often. It's possible that this is a regional thing - after a quick Google search just now, I noticed both being used. However, I consider "voluntary organization" to be incorrect from a purely grammatical viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

A volunteer is a person who does something of their own free will. Not mandatory to do it.

Voluntary means doing something and not receiving a cash payment.

In many instances volunteers do things on a voluntary basis.

Both words have very different meanings but can co exist.

E.g. A person volunteered to join the Police Service but doesn't do it on a voluntary basis. 
i.e. not mandatory but paid.

The Court found a person guilty of an offence and ordered him/her to 40 hours Community Service but its done on a voluntary basis.
i .e. mandatory but not paid.

A person volunteered to work with The Red Cross on a voluntary basis.
i.e. not mandatory and not paid.

A person was conscripted to the Armed Forces but it's not voluntary.
i.e. mandatory but paid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gareth, welcome to EL&U!  Please try to back up your answer with a citation.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Both are acceptable, but there is a slight difference in meaning. The better word would depend on the context in which you use it.

"Volunteer organization" means an organization of volunteers. This emphasizes the people in the organization. This often means a charity group that helps others.

"Voluntary organization" means an organization that is voluntary to join. This emphasizes that joining is optional, not mandatory. Another use of voluntary, "My boss gives me voluntary work if I ask for more responsibility."

For you, "volunteer organization" is the better word to use. "Volunteer work" is better for you than "voluntary work" as well.